# Nexus3 + Nginx Reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nexus3

I am trying to get Nexus3 to run behind Nginx.

Nginx is used as a reverse proxy and for SSL termination.  When accessing the /nexus path through Nginx, I get multiple errors such as "Operation failed as server could not be reached" and "unable to detect which node you are connected to".  Accessing the Nexus UI without going through Nginx works perfectly which lead me to think the error is on Nginx.

NginX Config File

```
location /nexus {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/nexus/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 ipv6=off;
    }
```

Comment: When accessing the Nexus UI without going through Nginx, does the URI include the `/nexus/` prefix?

Comment: It works without going through Nginx i.e. accessing the URL on http://localhost:8081/nexus/.  The URI does contain the context path /nexus/ I am using Nginx for SSL termination.

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/nexus;` (without a traling `/`) to match the `location` value. Also, try removing the `Host` header statement.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that sorted out the issue.  Please add as an answer so I may mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you access the service using `http://localhost:8081/nexus`, it works.

Your current configuration is using `proxy_pass` to change the URI `/nexus` to `/nexus/`. Generally, it is advisable to have a trailing `/` on both the `location` and `proxy_pass` URIs or on neither of them.

For example:

```
location /nexus {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/nexus;
    ...
}
```

In fact, you so not need to modify the URI at all, so you can remove it from the `proxy_pass` directive altogether.

The following should be equivalent, but more efficient:

```
location /nexus {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    ...
}
```

By default, the `Host` header is set to the value of the `proxy_pass` directive (i.e. `locatlhost:8081`), which is known to work correctly. You may find the your statement `proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;` is unnecessary.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: I find, on Nexus OSS 3.15.2-01, that leaving out the Host header results in a 400 Bad Request.  I have nginx listening on 8888 proxying to nexus at 8081.

Comment: You're life saver!!! In ALL nginx examples of proxy_pass it's always strictly advisable to include trailing slash! But for god knows why reasons this doesn't work for Nexus, but the suggested efficient option worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I sunk hours into this until I found your answer. Thank you.